# Data loss and Table 'xxxx.xxx' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mariadb, debian

I have a weird problem that is driving me crazy. Let's see if someone can help me.
This is my stage.

```
/# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

/# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

/# systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.48 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-01-23 12:14:01 CET; 23min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 1184 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1175 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1064 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_
  Process: 1059 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1057 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1139 (mysqld)
   Status: "InnoDB: Error: Table "gerkud_kirolak"."gertakaria" is corrupted. Please drop the table and recreate."
    Tasks: 29 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─1139 /usr/sbin/mysqld

ene 23 12:13:56 gerkud systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1.48 database server...
ene 23 12:13:57 gerkud mysqld[1139]: 2023-01-23 12:13:57 140007137725824 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2) starting as process 1139 ...
ene 23 12:14:01 gerkud systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.1.48 database server.
```

Due to a power outage, the ESXi hosts were turned off, consequently the virtual machines too. When turning on the virtual machine I find this problem.

In a database I have this error message:

```
MariaDB [gerkud_kirolak]> select * from gertakaria;
--------------
select * from gertakaria
--------------

ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'gerkud_kirolak.gertakaria' doesn't exist in engine
```

And in another database, data has disappeared from a date onwards.

What do you think could have happened?

Comment: My first instinct is to say - restore from a backup.  You probably had write caching enabled

Comment: I have not a SQL backup, i restored a VM complet backup and and the data is not here either.

Comment: Even if you could try and recover the file, the chances are extremely high that it will be corrupted, and not worth the effort.

Comment: So, you think i have had write caching enabled, and the last data was on cache and when turno off the machine, the data was lost?

Comment: Correct.  I normally turn off write caching in the database engine and on the drive that contains the database.

Comment: Ok, but i can't believe that it's possible to stay 2 month data on cache. You think it's possible? I have not data since 2022-11-30. And

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142270/discussion-between-xabikip-and-rohit-gupta).